# c++ qt QObject:: connect: No such slot

Tags: c++, qt, slot, qt-connection

I have defined my slot like this:

```
void choixPoints:: prendpixel1(Pixel depart)
{
//...
}
```

and I want to execute the following sentence:

```
Pixel depart= picmou->define(); //definition of a pixel, well defined 
connect(chp3, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(prendpixel1(Pixel depart)));
```

However when I execute I obtain:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot choixPoints::prendpixel1(Pixel depart)
```

Why doesn't my slot work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that in your SLOT definition you put a variable name "depart" in, which is not correct. The SLOT and SIGNAL definitions must only have the function name and types. So:

```
connect(chp3, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(prendpixel1(Pixel)));
```

BTW I think it is also space sensitive, so `SLOT(anotherfn(Pixel, Pixel))` would also be wrong.

HTH,Ruth

Answer (score 2):

Did you declare void choixPoints:: prendpixel1(Pixel depart) as a public slot in the header?
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#a-small-example

You also have to register your data type (here: "Pixel"):
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Qt_Signal/Slot_with_custom_data_types